# Ejecutar código cada cierto tiempo en segundos - Dart - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

¡Saludo programadores!

Actualmente me encuentro en un problema usando Flutter, y es que, requiero que se ejecute un código cada cierta cantidad de segundos, 10 para ser exactos...

El código que quiero que se ejecute en ese tiempo de manera indefinida es el siguiente:

```
await _bc.write([0x41, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 00, 65]);
```

¿Existe algo en Dart que me permita poder realizar lo que requiero?

¡Muchas gracias! ^^

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto: https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/65/how-to-execute-code-on-loop-with-time-interval-flutter-app/

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas que se ejecute mientras la aplicación esta abierta? o mientras esta en el background?

Para el caso 1 puedes usar un timer recurrente asi:

```
    Timer miTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 20), (timer) {
      //Este codigo se ejecuta cada 20 segundos
    });

miTimer.cancel(); // cancelar la ejecución
```

Para el segundo caso el tema es un poco mas complejo y tendrias que recurrir a funciones de background task, puedes echarle un ojo a esta libreria externa: https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: Hola, las aclaraciones se realizan como comentario, revisar [ask], saludos.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por tu comentario, para los dos casos realmente lo requiero... Ya lo solucione para qué se ejecute en la aplicación abierta, más adelante la haré en background, gracias.